# glusterfs client mount point fails with 'Client quorum is not met'

Tags: filesystems, cluster, glusterfs, distributed-filesystems

Assume a basic *replica 3 arbiter 1* configuration, *glusterfs-server 4.0.2* and *glusterfs-client 4.0.2*. 
*glusterfs-client* is installed on *Ubuntu 18.04*.

In order to verify that write / read ops are permitted when one storage node is down as stated in the [docs](https://docs.gluster.org/en/v3/Administrator%20Guide/arbiter-volumes-and-quorum/), an unexpected result occurs. After killing gluster processes on one of the non-arbiter nodes (using `pkill ^gluster*`) the client mount point fails with '`Client quorum is not met.`' ([see glusterfs-client log file](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/attachment.cgi?id=1456404)).

Gluster volume info:

```
Volume Name: brick01
Type: Replicate
Volume ID: 2310c6f4-f83d-4691-97a7-cbebc01b3cf7
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1 x (2 + 1) = 3
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: proxmoxVE-1:/mnt/gluster/bricks/brick01
Brick2: proxmoxVE-2:/mnt/gluster/bricks/brick01
Brick3: arbiter01:/mnt/gluster/bricks/brick01 (arbiter)
```

The volume is created by the following command

```
gluster volume create brick01 replica 3 arbiter 1 
proxmoxVE-1:/mnt/gluster/bricks/brick01 
proxmoxVE-2:/mnt/gluster/bricks/brick01 
arbiter01:/mnt/gluster/bricks/brick01
```

As stated per the [docs](https://docs.gluster.org/en/v3/Administrator%20Guide/arbiter-volumes-and-quorum/#how-arbiter-works), file ops should be allowed in cases when one brick is down (if arbiter is ok with that), then why do I get 'Client quorum is not met' on the client side?
After a significant time spent reading the official docs about `glusterfs`, I couldn't find explanation as to why this is happening, and also filed a [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1597821) on *Red Hat Bugzilla*.

Any help on the topic will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`gluster volume heal brick01 enablе` resolved the issue.

This eventually added the re-configured option `cluster.self-heal-daemon: enable` to the volume. It seems that by default arbiter brick fails to heal (sync) simultaneously when any file operation occurs and blames the other brick that is still up.